# Solid-Gauge de HighCharts No Me Deja Establecer en el un rango de algunos números

Tags: highcharts

```js
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Highcharts Example</title>

  <style type="text/css">
.highcharts-yaxis-grid .highcharts-grid-line {
 display: none;
}
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/5.0.14/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/5.0.14/js/highcharts-more.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/5.0.14/js/modules/solid-gauge.js"></script>

<div style="width: 600px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto">
    <div id="container-speed" style="width: 300px; height: 200px; float: left"></div>
    <div id="container-rpm" style="width: 300px; height: 200px; float: left"></div>
</div>




  <script type="text/javascript">


var gaugeOptions = {

    chart: {
        type: 'solidgauge'
    },

    title: null,

    pane: {
        center: ['50%', '85%'],
        size: '140%',
        startAngle: -90,
        endAngle: 90,
        background: {
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || '#EEE',
            innerRadius: '60%',
            outerRadius: '100%',
            shape: 'arc'
        }
    },

    tooltip: {
        enabled: false
    },

    // the value axis
    yAxis: {
        stops: [
            [0.1, '#55BF3B'], // green
            [0.5, '#DDDF0D'], // yellow
            [0.9, '#DF5353'] // red
        ],
        lineWidth: 0,
        minorTickInterval: null,
        tickAmount: 2,
        title: {
            y: -70
        },
        labels: {
            y: 16
        }
    },

    plotOptions: {
        solidgauge: {
            dataLabels: {
                y: 5,
                borderWidth: 0,
                useHTML: true
            }
        }
    }
};

// The speed gauge
var chartSpeed = Highcharts.chart('container-speed', Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 50,
        title: {
            text: 'Speed'
        }
    },

    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'Speed',
        data: [80],
        dataLabels: {
            format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;color:' +
                ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{y}</span><br/>' +
                   '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">km/h</span></div>'
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' km/h'
        }
    }]

}));

// The RPM gauge
var chartRpm = Highcharts.chart('container-rpm', Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 5,
        title: {
            text: 'RPM'
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'RPM',
        data: [1],
        dataLabels: {
            format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:25px;color:' +
                ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{y:.1f}</span><br/>' +
                   '<span style="font-size:12px;color:silver">* 1000 / min</span></div>'
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' revolutions/min'
        }
    }]

}));

// Bring life to the dials
setInterval(function () {
    // Speed
    var point,
        newVal,
        inc;

    if (chartSpeed) {
        point = chartSpeed.series[0].points[0];
        inc = Math.round((Math.random() - 0.5) * 100);
        newVal = point.y + inc;

        if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 200) {
            newVal = point.y - inc;
        }

        point.update(newVal);
    }

    // RPM
    if (chartRpm) {
        point = chartRpm.series[0].points[0];
        inc = Math.random() - 0.5;
        newVal = point.y + inc;

        if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 5) {
            newVal = point.y - inc;
        }

        point.update(newVal);
    }
}, 2000);



  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

En esta parte en el max le aplico un rango de 0 a 50, pero la gráfica lo que hace es que me lo lleva a 60, igual si en lugar de 50 coloco 15 el me lo pone en 16, no se si hay una forma de corregir esto.
        yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        max: 50,
        title: {
            text: 'Speed'
        }
    },[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es muy probable que el problema esté en las series que le estás dando. Al darte un máximo de 60, puedes poner la serie que le das?

Comment: La serie es la que trae por defecto la librería yo tome el codigo y hago los cambios en el el de la imagen es un ejemplo de como se ven, osea en data:[50] ese es lo que mando, en los parámetros max y min es que tengo la duda de como realizar lo y porque en la gráfica el valor máximo lo pasa de 50 que es el que yo le doy a 60